# Twentytwenty theme p-tags break em- and strong-tags that span several paragraphs

Tags: theme-development, tags, html

Going from twentysixteen to twentytwenty theme has disrupted formatting. As I understand WP2020 introduces p-tags within em- and strong- tags that are not closed. It looks like [screenshot one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrrjQ.jpg).

The code looks like this

```
dömer ut riksdagen istället för att ta en match med politikerna och försöka förbättra något.</em></p>
<p>poster2: <a href=https://www.example.com/p72842243#p72842243>72842243</a></p>
<p><em>Man kan inte omväxlande betrakta Greta både som en stor klimatauktoritet, men när konsekvenserna av hennes handlande blir uppenbara plötsligt gå över till att  betrakta henne som ett barn.</p>
<p>Hon har ju möten med t.ex Trudeau, Merkel, Obama, Corbyn, von der Leyen och håller anföranden om klimatet i en mängd stora församlingar. Men i Sverige står hon bakom riksdagshuset och kommenterar inte den svenska miljöpolitiken. Annars har hon inga problem att rabbla siffror om klimatet.</p>
<p>Får hon pris av Nordiska Rådet vägrar hon ta emot priset!</p>
<p>Gretas har blivit instruerad att följa en typisk globalistisk agenda med hat av det egna landet. Bl.a handlar det om att försöka flytta inflytande från riksdagen till Bryssel. Hon mobbar svenska politiker.</em></p>
<p>wwr: <a href=https://www.example.com/p72845620#p72845620>72845620</a></p>
<p><em>Poster1: <a href=https://www.example.com/p72844680#p72844680>72844680</a></p>
<p><em>Ska man vara riktigt petig fyller hon 18 om fyra månader men OK.</p>
<strong>Nu var frågan inte ställd till mig men, men. De allra flesta
```

I experimented with substitutions like

```
$tar = "/(<em>(.(?!<\/em>))*)<\/p>/";
$rep = "$1<\/em><\/p>";
$content = preg_replace($tar, $rep, $content);
```

But I never succeeded completely. So now I just close all strong- and em- tags before *every* /p-tag, which naturally is very ugly.

```
$tar = "/<\/p>/";
$rep = "</em></strong></p>";
```

It looks like [screenshot two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUVSJ.jpg).

The code is

```
dömer ut riksdagen istället för att ta en match med politikerna och försöka förbättra något.</em></em></strong></p>
<p>wwr: <a href=https://www.example.com/p72842243#p72842243>72842243</a></em></strong></p>
<p><em>Man kan inte omväxlande betrakta Greta både som en stor klimatauktoritet, men när konsekvenserna av hennes handlande blir uppenbara plötsligt gå över till att  betrakta henne som ett barn.</em></strong></p>
<p>Hon har ju möten med t.ex Trudeau, Merkel, Obama, Corbyn, von der Leyen och håller anföranden om klimatet i en mängd stora församlingar. Men i Sverige står hon bakom riksdagshuset och kommenterar inte den svenska miljöpolitiken. Annars har hon inga problem att rabbla siffror om klimatet.</em></strong></p>
<p>Får hon pris av Nordiska Rådet vägrar hon ta emot priset!</em></strong></p>
<p>Gretas har blivit instruerad att följa en typisk globalistisk agenda med hat av det egna landet. Bl.a handlar det om att försöka flytta inflytande från riksdagen till Bryssel. Hon mobbar svenska politiker.</em></em></strong></p>
<p>wwr: <a href=https://www.example.com/p72845620#p72845620>72845620</a></em></strong></p>
<p><em>poster1: <a href=https://www.example.com/p72844680#p72844680>72844680</a></em></strong></p>
<p><em>Ska man vara riktigt petig fyller hon 18 om fyra månader men OK.</em></strong></p>
<strong>Nu var frågan inte ställd till mig
```

This "fixes" most occurrences of the problem but not all.

There must be a better and simpler way to fix this problem. I have many em- and strong-tags that span over several paragraphs. Twentytwenty theme hacks up these tag contents with p-tags. How can I fix this?

Page [url](http://www.snowleopard.info/global/global_01/greta-thunberg-009/)

(I have probably broken some html standard by spanning paragraphs with em- and strong-tags. But writing posts I was not aware of this. I just put two empty lines within the em- or strong-tag. The p-tags are then added by WP. It used to work all right with twentysixteen theme.)

**Edit Dec 12:**
Deactivated most plugins one by one. Error persists. (Did not deactivate a few very spread plugins like Akismet, Classic editor, Enhanced Media Library PRO, Google language translator)

Now run twentytwenty child theme. Error persists with twentytwenty. Error disappears running twentysixteen and Complete lite.

Comment: I would love to suggest some debug steps to identify the source of the issue. We can easily say the issue is too localized and not the case for all. So some rudimentary debugging steps would help us identify where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Sorry missed the link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info

Comment: Thank you. It may be difficult for me to switch off all plugins at once. But I will do the debugging I can. So according to what you say the problem is not that I have put *multiple blank lines within text that is spanned by f.ex em-tags*? This practice should work also with twentytwenty theme?

Comment: Some debugging added to the post. Theme twentytwenty gives the error, not themes twentysixteen or Complete lite. To me it appears like connected to the theme but if other people can run twentytwenty and enter two blank lines (generating a p-tag in WP)  between paragraphs within the same em-tag, it would be something else.

Comment: `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );`

Comment: Thank you. As I interpreted your comment I should remove any filtering of the content. I have already disabled any plugin filtering content. Should I also run the code you suggested?

Comment: Actually, you are doing something wrong by core. `<em>` tag is an inline element, and `<p>` is a block-level element. In this point, `<em><p>p1</p><p>p2</p></em>` seems to me an invalid markup, and `<p><em>p1</em></p><p><em>p2</em></p>` should be a valid markup. If you need a line break instead of paragraph, use `Shift` + `Enter` instead of only `Enter`. With this you can have one single paragraph `<p><em>p1<br/>p2</em></p>` instead of two different paragraphs.

Comment: What you say I believe is true. I just write text and put two blank lines for a paragraph. And then I sometimes use the WP classical editor and select several paragraphs and press the em button. WP then generates the invalid html. (I can't do shift/enter on a phone) -- So I have 400 posts that generate invalid html in twentytwenty theme. But they work all right in twentysixteen and Complete light. I was hoping I could filter this but I only succeeded partially. Maybe I should just forget twentytwenty theme unless someone could come up with a solution. ...

Comment: ... my own solution in the future will be to never straddle blank lines with em or strong tags.

Comment: What I have to make one day is a program that reads the post from the database and when it finds two blank lines in an open em tag it adds a closing and and opening em tag. Some guys doing themes obviously do this. For the time being I will have to leave twentytwenty theme. -- I admittedly broke a html standard, but it is not easy to realize when you use the editor. You easily believe you write html and new lines would not imply a p-tag later.